# Log folder files extremely large can't log in

Tags: hard-drive, login, storage

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
A few days ago I couldn't log in to my account.
I logged in as Guest and received a notice that my hard drive is full.
I used Disk Usage Analyzer as was suggested to see what was going on (I do not store large amounts of information on the computer so a full HD was unexpected).
Disk Usage Analyzer noted that the var/log folder was using up the vast majority of my HD.
The folders in question are Kern.log1 (72gb), kern.log (193gb), syslog.2.gz (6.6gb).

I would like to delete these as I believe this is preventing me from logging in using my regular user account.

The main issue is that I can't delete these files as I can only log in using my Guest account. I feel like I'm locked out of my own computer and I'm the admin for it!

Any help would be appreciated.

So just after posting I tried to log in again in my regular account and it worked!
I however can't delete the offending files as I'm not the owner despite being the main user of the computer. 
Thoughts?

Comment: Boot a live USB and remove the "syslog.2.gz" , then look at the logs to see what is filling them.

Comment: I was able to get in. Funny just tried once again after the post. I found the files but can't edit them as I'm not the owner though I'm the only user.

Comment: you must use "sudo"when viewing /var/log/. `sudo tail -n 100 /var/log/kern.log` for instance will show the last 100 lines.

Comment: Though you think you are the only user of your system, you should know there are several pre-defined users withing the Ubuntu for running different works. you can run this command: `ls -l /var/log/sys*` and see the owner and group of the files (which is syslog and adm). You need to use `sudo` to be able to manipulate/delete these files

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 sudo -s
 shopt -s globstar                  # if needed
 truncate -s 0 /var/log/*.log       # first-level logs
 truncate -s 0 /var/log/**/*.log
```

Comment: Doesn't one usually open Terminal by using the search icon usually at the top of the menu bar? Can't seem to open or even find Terminal or find other applications using the search app.

Comment: ctrl + alt + T is the keyboard short cut to open the terminal window

Comment: Terminal responds that "permission is denied".  I tried to delete the content of these files once I regained entry to my account but I was told I wasn't the owner. I must leave my computer now but I will be back. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: you have to use sudo. and that is a temp fix, we need to look at the errors to see what is filling the logs.

Comment: updated with sudo -s at the top .

Comment: I would advice to remove /var/log/*.gz, then check the size of the log files and view the last 100 lines of the biggest log file. Fix the problem it shows. And then initfile the log files (do -not- delete them but empty them since software will depend on the log file being there).

Comment: I used the above script and the log files were reduced to 0 bytes. Excellent! I also used sudo rm to get rid of some of the log files with a number after them (i.e. kern.log1) and zipped log and sys files. I thought this would be okay as the OS is likely using only the kern.log and syslog without the sequential number. All seems to be working well. I shall use this again as per. Thank you very much!

Comment: I retained a sample of the contents from one kern.log and one syslog file. I couldn't get samples from all of them as they were so large they crashed gedit. It appears something went bad with my distributive computing software BOINC but the contents was incomprehensible to me. I.e.  kern.log
Mar 14 19:29:26 murray-BOINC6 kernel: [523996.734134] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] TRAP ch 6 [0x003fa93000 java[7973]]
Mar 14 19:29:26 murray-BOINC6 kernel: [523996.734144] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] GPC0/PROP trap: (unknown enum 0x00000002)  and on and on and on many entries every second.

Comment: Odd that this computer is the only one of 3 identical computers running BOINC which messed up. This one is regularly used to play Minecraft and has a better video card. Chrome is also installed along with Firefox. Besides these differences they have the same specs.

Comment: File a bug report with that error or your logs will continue to get full